# Why is this code drawing sprites in reverse order?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, sprite

I've got the following piece of code:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, cam.TransformMatrix);
spriteBatch.Draw(_comicBackground, workspace, Color.AliceBlue);
foreach (LayoutField lf in comicStrip.LayoutFields)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(_layoutFieldBackground, new Rectangle(lf.PosX, lf.PosY, lf.Width, lf.Height), Color.White);
}
spriteBatch.End();
```

but regardless of SpriteSortMode (FrontToBack | BackToFront) background is always being displayed on top of the results of `foreach` loop, covering my layout in the result.

It's not a show-stopper as I can draw my sprites in reverse order but I'd rather keep them in the order in which they should be drawn on the screen.

Comment: What happens when set the `SpriteSortMode` to `Deffered`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't have the time yesterday. `Deffered` mode worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FrontToBack` and `BackToFront` sort modes require you to specify a sprite depth value in your `Draw()` calls; see the `layerDepth` parameter [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx).  If you want to draw sprites in the order that you make the `Draw()` calls, use `SpriteSortMode.Deferred` or `SpriteSortMode.Immediate`.